# React-native how to bind RadioButton conditionaly?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux

I use RadioButton from https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-radio-button-group

and I need conditionaly hide 1 radio button element, if condition is true, everything works ok, but if condition is false, it throws error:
**React.cloneElement(...): The argument must be a React element, but you passed null.**

my code is below, see condition { false &&:

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import RadioButton, { RadioGroup } from "rn-radio-button-group";

export default function App() {
  const [langValue, setLangValue] = useState("");
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
        Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to get a shareable url.
      </Text>
<Text>Test</Text>

      <RadioGroup
        onValueChange={(value) => setLangValue(value)}
        selectedValue={langValue}
      >
        <RadioButton
          value={"green"}
          style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}
          size={27}
          color="green"
        >
          <Text style={{ marginLeft: 10, fontSize: 18 }}>Green</Text>
        </RadioButton>
        { false &&
        <RadioButton
          value={"red"}
          style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}
          size={27}
          color="red"
        >
        
          <Text style={{ marginLeft: 10, fontSize: 18 }}>Red</Text>
        </RadioButton>
        }

        <RadioButton
          value={"yellow"}
          style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}
          size={27}
          color="yellow"
        >
          <Text style={{ marginLeft: 10, fontSize: 18 }}>Yellow</Text>
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton
          value={"orange"}
          style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}
          size={27}
          color="orange"
        >
          <Text style={{ marginLeft: 10, fontSize: 18 }}>Orange</Text>
        </RadioButton>
      </RadioGroup>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

you can also find it here: https://snack.expo.dev/4Y96Oh0Xf

appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to do something like

```
{condition ? 
<RadioButtonComponent/> : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the below will work for you,

```
  { condition &&
   ( <RadioButton
      value={"red"}
      style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}
      size={27}
      color="red"
    >
   )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

the better approach you can make your own radio Buttons and play with your own conditions